# html isn't fully liquid

Tags: html, css, liquid

Hello I'm new to html & css and I have a question. I'm trying to make my page as liquid as possible but for some reason my button and h3 keep on colliding with the navbar. Can someone please help me ?

this is my html code:

```
<div id="content">
   <h2>Kleding</h2>
    <div id="navbanner">
    <div id="nav2">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#Pasgeborenen">Pasgeborenen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Baby">Baby</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Peuter">Peuter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Kleuter">Kleuter</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="img">
     <button onclick="ShowCheckBoxes()"><img src="../images/winkelwagen.jpg"></button>
    </div>
    <a name="Pasgeborenen"><h3>Pasgeborenen</h3></a>
</div>
```

and here is the css is use:

```
#content{
margin: 30px 0;
background: white;
padding: 20px;
clear: both;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #999;
}

#navbanner{
width: 100%;
height: 5.5em;
background: orange;
}
#nav2{
 text-align: center;

}
/* unorded list */
#nav2 ul{
 display: inline-block;
 list-style-type:none;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

#nav2 ul li{
 float:left;

}
 #nav2 ul li a:hover{
  background-color: #ffbc00;
  text-decoration: underline;
 }
/* text in blokken */
#nav2 ul li a{
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 1em;
 background: orange;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: large;
 color: white;
}
button{
 float: right;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Quick and dirty solution would be to add float:left to #nav2. Here's a n example http://jsfiddle.net/vladsaling/WWTug/

Comment: Is float a dirty code ? whut would be a good alternative ?

Comment: And btw by adding float:left the text will no longer be centered

Comment: Reworking the structure. Correct me if I am wrong, but first heading + nav seems to be the header structure. Second heading seems to be the beginning of actual content. You could separate these two elements to clearfixed wrappers and floated cells (much like css grids), that you can reuse trough-out the whole page.

Re text centering: let me put together example in js fiddle.

Comment: Here is the centering you need reworked. I checked your code again and biggest problem was, that you were setting specific height of the #navbanner. This made your heading collide with navigation http://jsfiddle.net/vladsaling/WWTug/ (simply put, if the viewport gets too naroow, the combined height of NAV is bigger, than 5.5em, but its wrapper won't stretch)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the height: 5.5em; from #navbanner. Rest of the code may stay as it is.

```
#navbanner{
width: 100%;
height: 5.5em; <- this has to go 
background: orange;
}
```